# How to deploy android application within sqlite db?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, deployment, tablet

I can not figure it out. I want to deploy my application to Xoom tablet. I am taking the apk file under bin directory and sending to xoom. but i could not achieve to run the applicaton with db. Where should i put db file? please i need help. it will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the .db into assets/, then access it from code with getAssets().open("some.db");